# Javascript Gadget Drive Api

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Can i write a Google XML Gadget that use the javascript drive api?
I tried to embed the code of the javascript quickstart, replaced the client-id, but it doesn't work.

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js

Thank you